# To prove or disprove the given Asymptotic notations

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory

## Prove or Disprove

1) ***max**{ f(n), g(n)}* = **O**(f(n) + g(n)), where f(n) and g(n) are positive functions.

2) ***min**{ f(n) , g(n)}* = **Ω**(f(n) + g(n)), where f(n) and g(n) are positive functions.

My proof for the first question is something like, *max* {f(n) + g(n)} would be > than f(n) + g(n). So setting the constant c to the *max* {f(n) + g(n)} will make the  Big'O condition hold true. Is this the right way to go about doing it? Also, I'm not sure as to how to go on to prove the secon question, so any help with regard to that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is correct. As `max(f(n),g(n)) < f(n) + g(n)`. The second one is incorrect. You can show that by contrdition. Suppose `f(n) = log(n)` and `g(n) = n`. We can see that `min(f(n),g(n)) = log(n)` but we know that `log(n)` is not `Omgea(n + log(n))`.